# How to validate ViewModel properties asynchronously with ReactiveUI c#?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I want to validate the properties of my view model with RxUI asynchronously. The validation should support dynamic error messages.
For example my ViewModel:

```
class MyWindowViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    private String _propToValidate;
    public String PropToValidate
    {
       get => _propToValidate;
       set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _propToValidate, value);
    }

    private async Task ValidatePropertyAsync(String propValue, CancellationToken ct)
    {
         var validationCode = await SendValidationRequest(propValue);
         String errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(validationCode);
    }
    
    public MyWindowViewModel()
    {
       // What should I add here to validate the PropToValidate asynchronously?
       // I didn't find any override of WhenAnyValue with Task support.           
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to validate the PropToValidate using RxUI asynchronously?

At this moment I do it by adding properties IsPropToValidateValid & PropToValidateMessage to the ViewModel. I create an observable at the construction for the PropToValidate & invoke the async validation there to change the IsPropToValidateValid & PropToValidateMessage.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its best not to call such logic from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree it would be not good to call the ValidatePropertyAsync method in the constructor directly. What is best to do in such a case?

Comment: I am not familiar with ReactiveUI, but; in other frameworks, you usally have something called the validation logic. Your `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`, if overridable might be such a place. I also notice you inherit from a validatable object: surly it has explicit methods to call the validation. In MVVM WPF, I tend to perform validation on PropertyChanged. ... which occurs when you try to set the property